# Java to DB connection exceptions

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jdbc

We are developing web application our tomcat server and mysql server runs on two different servers and we are getting the errors

```
org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed: 

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 86,402,200 milliseconds ago.

java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe

org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException:
```

need help to solve the issue

have tried the solutions from these links

[Hibernate Session Could not open for transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053684/hibernate-session-could-not-open-for-transaction)

[First Login: HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776095/first-login-http-status-500-request-processing-failed-nested-exception-is-or)

[com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai)

[com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai)

[com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065653/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception)

Comment: There is a problem in your MySql connection. Which URL are you using to connect the mysql?

Comment: Inside my db.property file i have this entry db.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://dbServerIp:3306/dbname

Comment: have you given network access to your db? You can verify your network access to your db by connection your local mySql client as below:
`mysql -h dbServerIp -u <user> -p<password>`

Comment: Yes i did actually we process about 14000 file but after around 6000 or 8000 files processed we are getting this exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the project is very big and multiple threads are running we were getting this error because we were exceeding the maximum number of connections that can be handled by the mysql server in our case 300.